# Import multiple images with sub_process and image_import

Tags: migrations

I have some nodes with multiple images I want to import. How can I combine `sub_process` plugin with `image_import`?

```
"field_image":[
    {"src":"https://example.com/image1.png","alt":"Image 1","title":"Image one."}, 
    {"src":"https://example.com/image2.png","alt":"Image 2","title":"Image two"}
]
```

What can I do to loop throw the array of images and import them later.

Here is example of my YML migration process configuration

```
process:
  nid: nid
  title: title
  field_image:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: field_image
    process:
      plugin: image_import
      source: src
      destination: constants/file_destination
      title: title
      alt: alt
```

Answer (score -1):

The YAML looks good although I fundamentally disagree with all these modules that try to inline several migrations into one.

I am not sure what your source plugin is. If I were doing this, I'd write a custom one by copying EmptySource and changing `id = "empty",` to `id = "my_json_source"` and change `initializeIterator` to `return new \ArrayIterator(json_decode($this->configuration['json_path'], TRUE)['field_image']);` and then

```
source:
  plugin: my_json_source
  json_path: path/to/my/json/file
```

That ought to work.

Comment: The question was specifically how to use the sub_process PROCESS plugin. Not how to set up the source.

Comment: Of course. You are right. You all are always right and know better than me. How could it be otherwise?